# Not able run my Lifeary 6.2.5 portlet project from liferay 7.0 portal

Tags: eclipse, jsf, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-7

**I am trying to  run my 6.2.5 portlet project  from liferay 7.x portal.**

In project facet under Runtime environment Liferay 7.x server is not visible.  Whenever I try to deploy war file into deploy folder of Liferay 7.0 ce portal or just run my project from liferay ide, Hot deploymentexception is being thrown along side  javax.xml.parsers:

> FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found

```
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.initDocumentParser(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:168)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.<init>(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:159)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.processFile(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:313)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.start(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:246)
    at org.quartz.plugins.SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.start(SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.java:144)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:2407)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:568)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:198)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListener(SecurePluginContextListener.java:355)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListeners(SecurePluginContextListener.java:163)
    ... 185 more
13:46:15,531 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][HookHotDeployListener:477] Registering hook for xxxxx
13:46:15,695 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][HookHotDeployListener:553] Hook for xxxxxxx is available for use
13:46:15,736 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][PortletHotDeployListener:202] Registering portlets for xxxxxx
13:46:16,045 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,138 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,217 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,350 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,493 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,585 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,685 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:16,770 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 4.2.5-ga6 (Philippi / Aug 11, 2015 AD)
13:46:18,250 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][PortletHotDeployListener:336] 8 portlets for xxxxxx are available for use
13:46:18,419 ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 30fd5ae1-6c3c-0016-1df2-b7f6f3c94f75][org_eclipse_equinox_http_servlet:97] FrameworkEvent ERROR 
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version of the Liferay Faces Bridge is not compatible with Liferay 7. You should use Bridge API `4.x`, Bridge Impl `4.x`, and Bridge Ext `5.x`. Since the Bridge has not been released for Liferay 7, you will need to use [SNAPSHOT builds](https://web.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/liferay-faces-project-news-april-2016). Here are the **`pom.xml`** dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.liferay.faces.bridge.impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.liferay.faces.bridge.api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.liferay.faces.bridge.ext</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If you have other Liferay Faces dependencies, check out [the Liferay Faces version scheme](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/understanding-the-liferay-faces-version-scheme#liferay-faces-version-scheme-for-releases-after-liferay-faces-ga6) for more information on which version(s) you should use.